# how to make MPAndroidChart PieChart show single slice in clockwise?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

MPAndroidChart is great! I tried to reach following goals with PieChart, but still does NOT work:

1, show only one slice in PieChart. I tried in this way: add two slices into DataSet and make one of them in transparent color, it works in some way, but not good enough.

2，make the only slice start from 0 angle and grows in clockwise. starting from angle 0 is ok, but failed to make it in clockwise

3，hide the text on slice

I have spend several hours in these questions...

[image]

Comment: You can make custom class which extends with `View` or `Drawable` class. Further you need to make first circle and after that according to your angles you need to draw a arc.

Comment: yes, I will turn to draw it myself if no answers anymore

Answer (score 1):

Check the levels of Y values. If there are at the same index, this error accures. 
For example:

```
yVals1.add( new Entry( 48.4 ,0 ) );
yVals1.add( new Entry( 51.6 ,1 ) );
```

Check the "0 - 1 " values.